# Splitting code accross two files that both require form data

Tags: php, refactoring, modularity

I'm trying to avoid a PHP script becoming too big and plan to create a file that will do some related tasks. My problem is that values submitted in a form are required in both and I'm not sure what the best approach to share data is.

After a user registers the form data is submitted to process.php which adds the data to the database and checks for duplicates. I'm now adding e-mail verification. I want everything to do with e-mail verification to be in it's own file, call it verify.php. Since both process.php and verify.php require data from the submitted form (e.g. username, e-mail address) what's the best way to share data? Here possible solutions I thought

1. Have the form submit to both process.php and verify.php (not sure if this is possible)
2. Have process.php include verify.php

   - in PHP would this automatically include the variables $_GET and $_POST from process.php?
3. After process.php finishes use a redirect header to go to verify.php and somehow pass it the form data

Generally speaking should including files be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Store the form data in $_SESSION and set it to expire after a given time period.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to *include* verify.php. Put the code there in functions and call them from process.php.

Answer (score 1):

> 2- Have process.php include verify.php

This is correct option, you can do something like this:

verify.php

Contains validation function such as:

```
function email_validation($email){
 //
}
```

Then you can send the argument like this:

```
if(email_validation($_GET['email'])){
 //
}
```

Don't use `global $var` and `$GLOBALS['var']` because [Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)